# Mobile Push received but links not working in Journey Builder

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, automationstudio, mobilepush, mobilestudio

Has anyone run into the problem of receiving mobile pushes from Journey Builder but with hardcoded links that simply don't work?

I am working on migrating our mobile pushes from the manual Mobile Studio process to the Journey Builder process. Our mobile pushes contain a specific link in our app and the desired functionality is to receive the push, swipe, and be taken directly to that specific page.

In Mobile Studio when we manually configure pushes, they are received and perform as desired.

In Journey Builder, the push is received but in Android tapping/swiping on the push does nothing (the app does not even open) and in iOS tapping/swiping only takes the user to the home page, not to the specified link.

We reviewed our configuration with Salesforce support and they did not notice any issues. The app push was built in Content Builder (not the Email Studio one), and each time we update the app push we create a new Version in the Journey. The journey is active with no errors, and everyone in our test audience does receive the new push. The link doesn't work. We have tried a regular https link, using TreatAsContent, creating a variable and calling the variable, creating a code snippet and using ContentBlockbyId, and nothing works. All of these do work in the manual Mobile Studio.

We have also used an App Push Activity in an Automation instead, but it performs the same way Journey Builder does (Android doesn't open at all, iOS only opens to home screen).

We have also created other Journeys to see if this Journey I am using is just corrupt somehow, but the same problem persists.

Has anyone run into the problem of receiving mobile pushes from Journey Builder but with hardcoded links that simply don't work? I appreciate all help!

Comment: What do you get when when you long-press on the link in the app, copy it from your device and paste it into wheregoes.com?

Comment: @AdamSpriggs I don't get a copy/paste option on my device when I long press it. It looks like that would need to be enabled on the developer side with allowsLinkPreview for iOS and maybe something else for Android, right?